# Adding an additional column containing file name to pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, python-os

I am iterating through csv files in a folder using for loop and performing some operations on each csv (getting the count of rows for each unique id and storing all these outputs into a pyspark dataframe). Now my requirement is to add the name of the file as well to the dataframe for each iteration. Can anyone suggest some way to do this

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the file name as a column using the function `pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name`, and if your files have the same schema, and you want to apply the same processing pipeline, then don't need to loop on these files, you can read them using a regex:

```
df = spark.read.csv("path/to/the/files/*.csv", header=True, sep=";") \
    .withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())
```